# Not able to activate new environment with conda

Tags: conda

Despite the fact that there are lots of discussions on this topic, I am not able to find a true solution to activate any new environments created using either regular methods, or yml with conda.

I am using Anaconda 4.4.10

I created an environment as below, using the following two methods mentioned in the [official document](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)

`conda create --name myenv`

and

`conda env create -f environment.yml`

Now I have two new env: py36 and rxie-env:

```
$ conda env list
py36 /home/hadoopuser/.conda/envs/py36
rxie-env /home/hadoopuser/.conda/envs/rxie-env
base * /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda
```

with `conda activate` I got the following error:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
>   use 'conda activate'. If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant,
>   enable conda for the current user with
>
> `$ echo ". /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >>
>   ~/.bashrc`
>
> or, for all users, enable conda with
>
> `$ sudo ln -s /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
>   /etc/profile.d/conda.sh`
>
> The options above will permanently enable the
>   'conda' command, but they do NOT put conda's base (root) environment
>   on `PATH`. To do so, run
>
> `$ conda activate` in your terminal, or to put the base environment on
>   `PATH` permanently, run
>
> `$ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc`
>
> Previous to conda 4.4, the
>   recommended way to activate conda was to modify `PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`
>   file. You should manually remove the line that looks like ...........
>   `export PATH="/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin:$PATH"`
>
> ^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your `~/.bashrc` file! ^^^

However, by following the given instruction I did the following:

1. `echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc`
2. `source ~/.bashrc` (not mentioned in the prompt but I think it is
   needed)
3. remove `export PATH="/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin:$PATH"`

   Now I have another new error below:

> -bash: /home/jhelmus/workspace/misc/cdh_parcel/anaconda/scripts/parcel/tmp/Anaconda-5.1.0/bin/conda:
>   No such file or directory

As you can see the error points to the conda developer jhelmus's home directory.

> jhelmus: https://anaconda.org/jjhelmus

Who can tell me what is the right secret command to get the new env activated?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so the answer is this version of Anaconda has bug, upgrade to higher version resolved this issue.